# How to run an executable file contained in a text file(hex of exe)

Tags: python, hex, exe, hexdump

I have a txt file containing hex of an exe. I read that file in python, but failed to run that .exe file.
any kind of help will be appriciated...

thanx

```
import binascii

def getExeFile():
    file1=input("Enter an exe file name(path):")
    with open(file1, 'rb') as f:
        content1 = f.read()
        bucket1=open("f1.txt", 'w')
        bucket1.write(str(binascii.hexlify(content1)))
        print(binascii .hexlify(content1))
        bucket1.close()
def getNonExeFile():
    file2=input("Enter a non-exe file name(path):")
    with open(file2, 'rb') as f:
        content2 = f.read()
        bucket2=open("f2.txt", 'w')
        bucket2.write(str(binascii.hexlify(content2)))
        print(binascii .hexlify(content2))
        bucket2.close()
getExeFile()
getNonExeFile()
print("End")
```

Answer (score 2):

Dump it to a temporary file; Change it's permissions so it's executable and run it in a subprocess

**Example:**

```
from os import chown
from subprocess import check_call
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
    f.write(get_hex_from_file("mydata.dat"))

chown(f.name, 0755)
check_call(f.name)
```

*Of course I'm making the assumption here that you are doing this on some kind of UNIX machine and that "EXE" in this case means some kind of ELF/A.OUT/COFF executable!* -- Nevertheless; same principles and code (with some tweaking) would probably work on other paltforms; e.g: Windows.

See:

- [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile)
- [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call)
- [`os.chown`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chown)

Comment: Dear James Mills, I am new at python, want to learn how python is used to manipulate with exes and and other files...
I need brief answer to run those files I've stored in a hex form in a txt file.
If you are could help me, I can show you my code.

thanx

Comment: I am reading an exe file creating its hex using binassci and stored it in a new text file... I want to run that text file using some python commands.

is it possible?

Comment: Sorry trying to "implement" your "whole solution" here would spoil the answer I provided that should help you with a bit of effort and learning on your part. You will learn nothing from "copying" and "pasting" a ready-to-go solution.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.4:
 This is my code that create a simple txt file having hex of and exe and a txt file.
Now I want my program to take that hex file and run the exe file and open the txt file.

import binascii

```
def getExeFile():
    file1=input("Enter an exe file name(path):")
    with open(file1, 'rb') as f:
        content1 = f.read()
        bucket1=open("f1.txt", 'w')
        bucket1.write(str(binascii.hexlify(content1)))
        bucket1.close()
def getNonExeFile():
    file2=input("Enter a non-exe file name(path):")
    with open(file2, 'rb') as f:
        content2 = f.read()
        bucket2=open("f2.txt", 'w')
        bucket2.write(str(binascii.hexlify(content2)))
        bucket2.close()
getExeFile()
getNonExeFile()
print("End")
```

Thanx...!